# Laravel Controllers Construct, правильно ли я использую конструктор?

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

class UsersController extends Controller
{

```
protected $user;
protected $users;
protected $p_d;
protected $ac;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('can:admin-author');
    $this->user = new User();
    $this->users = $this->user->all();
    $this->p_d = new PersonalData();
    $this->ac = new Access();
}

public function index()
{


    $data = [
        'users' => $this->user->orderBy('id')->paginate(10),
        'info' => $this->p_d->orderBy('user_id')->paginate(10),
    ];
    return view('admin.users.index')->with('data', $data);
}
```

}

Подскажите, является ли правильным использование конструктора таким способом?
Есть ли какие-то нюансы в использования конструктора, нужно ли использовать деструктор, при вызове функции  из "routes/web.php"?

Как работает этот "момент", когда из маршрутизации я вызываю через

```
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store']]);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как он задействует память и как он будет вести себя, если на сайте будет находится 100-500 человек?

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда приводите код текстом. Так с ним будет проще работать.

Comment: Вы в каждом экшене используете те данные которые запросили в конструкторе? Потому что в том же индексе вы вызываете два запроса и при этом список пользователей у вас всегда будет запрашиваться. Что касается остального... Тут больше моё мнение, но зачем в контроллер юзеров вы суёте ещё какую-то сущность?

Comment: Касательно "этот момента", такая запись говорит что в ресурсном маршруте будут отсутствовать экшены из этого списка

Comment: @Walfter 6 функций, и в 5 из них использую данные, которые в конструкторе запросил. Про сущности: Сложная бд и отображение некоторых страниц. Например страница Вакансий в себе должна иметь: пользователя на данной вакансии, проект(относящийся к вакансии) и саму вакансию. То есть 3 сущности. Также и в Users, есть Personal_data = личные данные и access = доступ пользователя

Comment: Они связаны с User? Если связаны то не проще через связи брать?

Comment: @Walfter Как это делать через связи?